# How to hide a component at runtime?

Tags: delphi, intraweb

Using IntraWeb 14.1 and Delphi Berlin, 
I'm creating and parenting a frame inside a `IWRegion` like this:

```
 Page := TFrame.Create(Self);
 Page.Parent := UserSession.Body_Region;
```

where `UserSession.Body_Region;` is decleared as `Body_Region: TIWRegion;` in `UserSessionUnit` to pass that region from form to form at runtime, and all works fine.

The problem is that **I want to hide the Frame** loaded inside the `UserSession.Body_Region` at runtime which is `UserSession.Main_Body_Region.Component[0];` but I couldn't do it.

I've tasted it with

```
(UserSession.Main_Body_Region.Component[0] as TFrame).hide;
```

or

```
(UserSession.Main_Body_Region.Component[0] as TFrame).Visible:= false;
```

but it's not working! also there is no errors!

is there any other way to do so or did I miss something here?

Comment: I've tried it with {Visible} but I've tried the {Enable} to check if this code responds or not and past it here by mistake, so in both case {Visible/Enable} its not working.

Comment: Perhaps setting `property RenderInvisibleControls: Boolean;` (of `TIWRegion`) `False` will help? See the [docs](http://docs.atozed.com/docs.dll/intraweb%20components/standard/TIWRegion.html)

Comment: You r right, I've set the property `RenderInvisibleControls` to false and the code started to work like a charm

Comment: I think this can be beneficial to know for other users too, so I made a proper answer about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the [documentation](http://docs.atozed.com/docs.dll/intraweb%20components/standard/TIWRegion.html) says that the

> `TIWRegion` control is the IntraWeb equivalent of the TPanel from VCL.

it has a difference that is important to consider:

`property RenderInvisibleControls: Boolean;` inherited from `TIWBaseContainer`

The documentation describes it as

> Use this property to inform that any control that has Visible = False
>   when the container it is rendered will also be rendered along with the
>   visible controls. This is particulary useful when you need to change
>   the visibility of controls using Async events.

IOW, setting this property to `False` will stop child components with `Visible = False` from being rendered.